# Move element by a fixed step

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to move an SVG element by 5pixels step, here is my function:

```
  onMouseMove = (e) => {
    const xDiff = this.coords.x - e.clientX;
    const yDiff = this.coords.y - e.clientY;

    let movex = this.state.x - xDiff;
    let movey = this.state.y - yDiff;
    while ( !(movex % 5) ) {
      movex++;
    }
    while ( !(movey % 5) ) {
      movey++;

    }
    this.setState({
      x: movex,
      y: movey,
    });
```

How can I have such an effect?

Comment: `let movex = Math.floor((this.state.x - xDiff) / 5) * 5);`

Comment: You can also remove the `!`s, because currently the test is the opposite of what you want.